# Datatables editable select not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, jeditable

I am using jquery-datatables-editable to edit a table.  Everything is working fine for text inputs and datepickers but when I attempt to populate a select it is always empty.

The code I am using is:

```
$("#eventsTable").dataTable(
{
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
        "bSortable": false,
        "aTargets": [5]
    } ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "<%=LanguageFieldsList.translate("There are no events")%>"
    }
})
.makeEditable(
{
    sUpdateURL: "ForecastManager?cmd=updateForecastEvent",
    aoColumns: [
        {
            indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
            event: "click",
            type: "text",
            onblur: "submit"
        },
        {
            indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
            event: "click",
            type: "datepicker",
            datepicker: {
                dateFormat: datePickerDateFormat,
                monthNamesShort: datePickerNames.monthNamesShort,
                dayNamesMin: datePickerNames.dayNamesMin,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            },
            onblur: "submit"
        },
        {
            indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
            event: "click",
            type: "datepicker",
            datepicker: {
                dateFormat: datePickerDateFormat,
                monthNamesShort: datePickerNames.monthNamesShort,
                dayNamesMin: datePickerNames.dayNamesMin,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            },
            onblur: "submit"
        },
        {
            indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
            event: "click",
            type: "text",
            onblur: "submit"
        },
        {
            indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
            event: "click",
            type: "select",
            onblur: "submit",
            loadurl: "ForecastManager?cmd=loadForecastEventSelect"
        }
    ]
});
```

As you can see when the last column is clicked I am attempting to populate the select by going to "ForecastManager?cmd=loadForecastEventSelect", this works and returns the JSON string:

```
{"0": "No Event","1": "Event 1","2": "Event 2"}
```

But the select is blank, however when i directly put this JSON string as a data option:

```
{
    indicator: "<img src='/Shared/img/loading.gif' alt='Saving...'/>",
    event: "click",
    type: "select",
    onblur: "submit",
    data: '{"0": "No Event","1": "Event 1","2": "Event 2"}'               
}
```

This populates the select successfully.  Does anyone have any idea why when I use loadurl the JSON is being ignored?

UPDATE:

I figured out the problem it was because I was setting the reponse content type to application/json.  Changing it to text/html populates the select successfully.